# hello I have a problem to send a error message in nodejs for the login

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
module.exports.signInErrors = (err) => {
    let errors = { email: '', password: ''}
  
    if (err.message.includes("email")) 
      errors.email = "Email inconnu";
    
    if (err.message.includes('password'))
      errors.password = "Le mot de passe ne correspond pas"
  
    return errors;
  }
```

and the results in postman is

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": "",
        "password": ""
    }
}
```

or I need to send the specifique errors

its imported

module.exports.signInErrors = (err) => {
let errors = { email: '', password: ''}

```
if (err.message.includes("email")) 
  errors.email = "Email inconnu";

if (err.message.includes('password'))
  errors.password = "Le mot de passe ne correspond pas"

return errors;
```

}

Comment: Hey, have you checked if the conditions `err.message.includes("email"` and `err.message.includes('password')` are actually true?
If yes, we need some more context

Comment: first of all check whether err.message contains "email" or "password" keywords or not

Comment: What does your "err" argument looks like?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code, i assume that both of your if statements are false.

Which leads to send empty values in your object.

Can you show where the `signInErrors` is called ?